# Close popover panel when button (operator) is pressed?

Tags: scripting, interface, operator, panel

Basically what the title says. After pressing a button/operator in a popover panel, I would like to close it.

I have no idea how, and I wasn't able to find anything in the manual. I made a litle reproduction script:

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "HelloWorldPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        
        layout.popover("PopoverPanel")
        


class PopoverPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "data"
    bl_label = "Move to"
    # bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED', 'HEADER_LAYOUT_EXPAND'}
    


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        layout.label(text="I want to close the popup after pressing:")
        layout.operator("object.simple_operator", text="press to close popup")




        
        
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Hello! After that I would like to close the popup!")
        return {'FINISHED'}



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PopoverPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PopoverPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The goal is to close the popover after executing `SimpleOperator`